# sqlite как объединить строки

Tags: python, sqlite

у меня есть база данных

```
name age id 

 10   4   1
 23   5   1
 45   9   2
```

как мне объединить в одну строку строки с id 1, чтобы получилось вот так

```
 name   age    id 
 10 23  4 5    1  
  45     9      2
```

Comment: А зачем тебе это? Так ведь данные хранить вообще неудобно -_-

Comment: а сделать где надо? в питоне или эскуэль?